# Url.Link requires request parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to set the location header on a web api post method if the item was inserted successfully, but problem is if I try to call that api action from a mvc controller it gives me an exception on Url.Link saying parameter 'request' is missing. Is there a way to generate the url without needing the request?

Here is the web api post code -

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post (Product product)
{
    ...
    if (addedSuccessfully)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage {StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created};
        var uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new {id = product.ProductId});
        if (uri != null)
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
    return new HttpResponseMessage {StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Conflict};
}
```

Here is how I am calling it

```
_productController.Post(product);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should not create web API controllers and start invoking actions on them unless you are unit testing. Controller's have context that gets initialized by the web API system when they are created internally.

If you could explain your scenario as in what you are doing with the HttpResponseMessage that gets returned from web API, may be I could present an alternative to solve it.

Comment: I wanted to write the "posting" logic once and let it be usable from both javascript ajax calls and the mvc side. I think what I should do is add the few extra lines to the mvc controller to call the data access layer. A little duplication of code/functionality but what to do